# Package Installation Option: Automatically attempt to rename conflicting components in installing package

Tags: managed-package

One of the steps when installing a namespaced managed package is shown below. What will the ***Automatically attempt to rename conflicting components in installing package*** option do when there's a conflict? It sounds as if components within the managed package that is being installed will be renamed.

I always thought that a managed package was a self-contained application that cannot be modified. Is there any documentation on how this renaming is done? Or how a conflict could occur when the managed package has a namespace?

[image: Package Conflict Options]

Comment: Can we triple check it's a _Namespaced Managed Package_ vs an _Unmanaged Package_?

Comment: Its a namespaced managed package. Ive updated the question

Comment: Even un/managed Page Layouts can coexist with the same name. Can you "Block installation and list conflicts" and click "Next" to show us the Component Types affected?

Comment: I have always used "Block installation and list conflicts" and its never had any conflicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only documentation i have found, which is under unmanaged, is in the excellent [ISV Force Guide](https://na5.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf). Which provides the following summary and a table. I've also included below information on managed packages for reference. I'd say if your definitely seeing this for a managed package and according my interpretation of the authoritative ISV packaging guide, it's a bug and something you should raise with Salesforce support.

**Components Available in Unmanaged Packages**

(extract from ISV Force Guide)

> Automatic Renaming
>   Salesforce can resolve naming conflicts automatically on install.
>
> - No: If a naming conflict occurs the install is blocked.
> - Yes: If a naming conflict occurs Salesforce can optionally change the name of the component being installed.

[image]

(see documentation for the full table)

**Special Behavior of Components in Packages**

(extract from ISV Force Guide)

> Component names must be unique within an organization. To ensure that your component names do not conflict
>   with those in an installer’s organization, use a managed package so that all of your component names contain you
>   namespace prefix.

Also...

> Tip: To prevent naming conflicts, Salesforce recommends using managed packages for all packages that contain
>   Apex. This way, all of the Apex objects contain your namespace prefix. For example, if there is an Apex class
>   called MyHelloWorld and the namespace for your organization is OneTruCode, the class is referenced as
>   OneTruCode.MyHelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

Besides the link Andrew Fawcett posted, there is this documentation page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_unmanaged_components.htm

Comment: Please include a summary of the linked document in case the link breaks. See [answer] for best practices.